# How To Open PDFdocument Through Windows Phone 8 App Which Is From Asset Folder

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need to open a pdf document file from the asset folder from windows phone 8 app. First I need to check whether any pdf reader is available or not and if available, the pdf document should be opened from the asset folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of using a file. You can mark it as

- Resource Files: Data files that are compiled into either an executable or library assembly. To access a resource,

Example :

```
Stream jsStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("folder\\e_data.pdf",UriKind.Relative)).Stream;
```

- Content Files: Standalone data files that have an explicit association with an executable assembly.

To access content file, use

```
Uri filePath = new Uri(@"ms-appx:///example.pdf");
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync();
```

EXAMPLE

Mark the pdf file as `content` in properties -> build action.

```
async void openPDF()
{
    Uri filePath = new Uri(@"ms-appx:///example.pdf");
    StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(filePath);
    //For opening that file,
    if (file != null)
        await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
}
```

Comment: Error 1 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'. D:\VisualStudioProjects\GK\GK\MainPage.xaml.cs error showing in code

Comment: add async keyword to your function header like `async void openPDF()`